Azure Blob Storage Put Blob from URL from Salesforce Apex : Error: OutOfRangeInput
I'm attempting to put blobs into Azure Blob Storage from Salesforce that are over 12MB.
I am using Put Blob from URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob-from-url and i have it working with public images but cannot get it to work with salesforce 'public' links to content documents.
I have tried the DistributionPublicUrl and the contentdownloadurl from content distribution but i am getting a Out Of Range error from azure.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Currently using PUT Blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob from a remote server to bypass apex limits is not an option.
I'm getting the below error,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code>
    <Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:749fb49e-101e-001b-6247-a2d651000000
Time:2024-05-09T19:29:08.9534310Z</Message>
</Error>


Please check if you can make an HTTP HEAD request (using Postman or something) for your Salesforce URL.

I'm using postman and my salesforce link is as below,
https://providenceadm--vssdev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/D30000008rJg/a/D3000000Gnc6/zR586YRm.PQaRLsEFUhU0BuvUg0gw1FOMawqtz9sLHY
or
https://providenceadm--vssdev.sandbox.file.force.com/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00DD30000008rJg&ids=068D3000005Il3x&d=%2Fa%2FD3000000Gnc6%2FzR586YRm.PQaRLsEFUhU0BuvUg0gw1FOMawqtz9sLHY&asPdf=false

I noticed in the 2nd link that it is automatically downloading the file. Please create a link that does not download the file automatically and try to use that in your code.

I tried using this link, which doesn't download the file automatically, but I still get the same error.
https://providenceadm--vssdev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#D30000008rJg/a/D3000000Gnc6/zR586YRm.PQaRLsEFUhU0BuvUg0gw1FOMawqtz9sLHY


< Error>    OutOfRangeInput     One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:749fb49e-101e-001b-6247-a2d651000000 Time:2024-05-09T19:29:08.9534310Z</ Message>

Initially, I also got the same error when I tried with the same public salesforce URL.

The error may be an issue with the Salesforce URL (like special characters). Alternatively, I tried with a different public URL (23 Mb) which worked perfectly.
Request:
PUT https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.bmp?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-05-10T11:47:18Z&st=2024-05-10T03:47:18Z&spr=https&sig=wqUJf8xxxx
Headers: 
x-ms-blob-type: Blockblob
x-ms-copy-source: <my public url>
x-ms-version: 2023-11-03

Output:

Portal:

Reference:
Here, you can refer to the below links with similar errors:

Azure CLI returns error on Storage access - Stack Overflow
Azure CLI throwing OutOfRangeInput error while uploading build artifact to the blob storage in the release pipeline - Stack Overflow
Azure Blob Storage - OutOfRangeInput on UploadBlobAsync - Stack Overflow


HI Venkatesan,
Thanks for the update and the mockup.
The salesforce public URL I'm using is as below,
https://providenceadm--vssdev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#D30000008rJg/a/D3000000Gnc6/zR586YRm.PQaRLsEFUhU0BuvUg0gw1FOMawqtz9sLHY
I don't see any special characters.
Thanks,

@VishwamberShetty
You can create azure support request by refering this link.
